# How to return a JSON response from a before block

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am writing a Sinatra-based API, and want to protect certain endpoints with an API key, validating the key before the route is processed.

I understand why throwing an error in the `before` block doesn't work, because the `begin`/`rescue` statements haven't been called yet, however I want a JSON response to be sent back to the client with the error message as a JSON object.

How would I do this?

```
namespace '/v1/sponser/:key' do

  before do
    if APIHelper.valid_key?(params[:key]) == false
      throw 'Error, invalid API key'
      # is it possible to return a JSON response from the before statement here?
    end
  end

  get '/test' do
    begin
      json status: 200, body: 'just a test'
    rescue => error
      json status: 404, error: error
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [`halt`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sinatra/sinatra/Sinatra%2FBase%3Ahalt):

```
before do
  unless APIHelper.valid_key?(params[:key])
    halt 404, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 
              { error: 'Error, invalid API key' }.to_json
  end
end

get '/test' do
  json status: 200, body: 'just a test'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `halt` method to return response with specific code, body and headers. So it looks like this:

`before do
  halt 401, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, '{"Message": "..."}'
end`

It looks sloppy so you can just redirect to another url, that provide some service